# ¿Cómo hago para que me carguen las imágenes en Laravel en produccion?

Tags: laravel, cpanel

Tengo el siguiente problema en mi proyecto tengo una tabla que registra datos con imagenes dichas imagenes las almacena en storage y las toma de ahí con storage:link y en local me funciona correctamente pero el problema viene cuando lo llevo a producción.

**En la vista asi mando llamar las imagenes**

```
<td>
     <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="{{ asset('storage').'/'.$dato->foto }}" alt="" width="100">
</td>
```

**Al actualizar no me muestra la imagen las que se mustran son las que ya estaban cargadas enteriormente en local**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi .env en APP_URL=http tengo la que corresponde.

Me han dicho que tengo que cargar el storage:link también en servidor, el cual uso cpanel como servidor compartido.

¿Cómo hago para cargar el storage que no tome el del local sino el de producción?

Comment: ¿Cómo hago esa ruta?

Comment: Ya he solucionado el problema lo que pasa es que tenía que eliminar la carpeta storage en public y crear el enlace con la siguiente ruta:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Route::get('/cmd/{command}', function($command){
    Artisan::call($command);
    dd(Artisan::output());
});

Answer (score 1):

Ya he solucionado el problema lo que pasa es que tenía que eliminar la carpeta storage en public y crear el enlace con la siguiente ruta para correr el comando desde la web:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Route::get('/cmd/{command}', function($command)
{
  Artisan::call($command); dd(Artisan::output());
});
```

Sólo que a veces no funciona si no está instalado php-cli en el servidor. Está ves me funciono.